# Empty $_POST Array parsing JS Object to PHP via JSON

Tags: php, json

I assume some of you might be already rolling their eyes since my topic has been dealt with so often in this forum. However, I haven't found any solution yet in this forum.

I want to parse a JS Object to a receiving PHP Site via JSON. I already read numerous times about the right parameters for the XMLHttpRequest-Header and its impact on the PHP part. I tried the very same solutions given in several other forums, but IT SIMPLY DOESN'T WORK for me. I've been working on this whole issue for four month now. I really need some advice.

Here is my JSON encoding JS Script:

```
function saveToDB(knotItems) {


  var txtobj = knotItems;

  var json = JSON.stringify(txtobj);

  var url = "http://localhost/projektplaner/tools/DBConnection/writeFileToDB.php";

  rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rq.open("post", url, true);
  rq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;   charset=UTF-8');

  rq.send("project=" + json);
  rq.onreadystatechange = window.open(url);

}
```

This is the JS-generated object array knotItems after being stringified by JSON:

```
[{
  "rank": 1,
  "name": "Baugrube",
  "faz_obj": "2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z",
  "fazInDays": null,
  "faz_string": "19.5.2016",
  "faz_timestamp": 1463680336402,
  "d": "2",
  "parallelTask": "seriell",
  "fez": ["2016-05-21T17:52:16.402Z", "21.5.2016", "NaN2"],
  "fez_dateObj": "2016-05-21T17:52:16.402Z",
  "fez_string": "21.5.2016"
}, {
  "rank": 2,
  "name": "Kellerwände",
  "faz_obj": "2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z",
  "fazInDays": null,
  "faz_string": "21.5.2016",
  "faz_timestamp": 1463853136402,
  "d": "4",
  "parallelTask": "seriell",
  "fez": ["2016-05-25T17:52:16.402Z", "25.5.2016", "NaN4"],
  "fez_dateObj": "2016-05-25T17:52:16.402Z",
  "fez_string": "25.5.2016"
}, {
  "rank": 3,
  "name": "Kellerdecke",
  "faz_obj": "2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z",
  "fazInDays": null,
  "faz_string": "25.5.2016",
  "faz_timestamp": 1464198736402,
  "d": "5",
  "parallelTask": "seriell",
  "fez": ["2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z", "30.5.2016", "NaN5"],
  "fez_dateObj": "2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z",
  "fez_string": "30.5.2016"
}]
```

The reason I post the variable content is to show that all object keys are in double quotes, as required by PHP's json_decode.

This is my PHP receiving script:

```
if(isset($_POST['project']))
{
    echo json_decode($_POST['project'],true); 
}
else
{
    echo "Keine Daten";    // No Data
}
```

This is the parameter payload that can be seen via Firebug analysis:

project:"[{"rank":1,"name":"Baugrube","faz_obj":"2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z","fazInDays":null,"faz_string":"19.5.2016","faz_timestamp":1463680336402,"d":"2","parallelTask":"seriell","fez":["2016-05-21T17:52:16.402Z","21.5.2016","NaN2"],"fez_dateObj":"2016-05-21T17:52:16.402Z","fez_string":"21.5.2016"},{"rank":2,"name":"Kellerwände","faz_obj":"2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z","fazInDays":null,"faz_string":"21.5.2016","faz_timestamp":1463853136402,"d":"4","parallelTask":"seriell","fez":["2016-05-25T17:52:16.402Z","25.5.2016","NaN4"],"fez_dateObj":"2016-05-25T17:52:16.402Z","fez_string":"25.5.2016"},{"rank":3,"name":"Kellerdecke","faz_obj":"2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z","fazInDays":null,"faz_string":"25.5.2016","faz_timestamp":1464198736402,"d":"5","parallelTask":"seriell","fez":["2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z","30.5.2016","NaN5"],"fez_dateObj":"2016-05-30T17:52:16.402Z","fez_string":"30.5.2016"}]"

HTTP Status Code is always 200 (OK).

And this is what I get from the PHP File.

Notice: Undefined index: project in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektplaner\tools\DBConnection\writeFileToDB.php on line 7
Keine Daten

I don't want to sound melodramatic or anything, but I'm about to go ape. I just can't see what the hell is wrong. Could it be a Server configuration issue?

I really, really appreciate your help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your content type should be `'application/json` because that's what you're sending it. It can't see `project:` as being an index as `form-encoded`

Comment: Thank you, Ohgodwhy... I already tried altering the Header params, unfortunately no difference.. 

    rq.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=UTF-8'); 



but wouldn't that also mean that I had to use file_get_contents on the php part? 

Btw.: Thanks for editing the variable content part, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: So, changing to 'application/json didn't do the trick, I'm sorry...

Comment: Are you trying open a new window or it is just as a exemplate?

Comment: No, i wanted it to open a new window, so I can instantly see whether the php page has received the data

Comment: I've now discovered that, despite my .open request in the JSON part is set to "post", 

    rq.open("post", url, true);

when I have the request method printed out via $_SERVER, it is somehow set to "GET". 
I tried to rewrite the entire script using the GET-Method everywhere, but it still doesn't work. Please, anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong...